# Session regenerate id and session_save_path( );

Tags: php

Hello I have this script below:

```
 <?php
   session_save_path('sessions/');
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
    }
   $loginUsername = A;

   if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true); } else {session_regenerate_id();}
$_SESSION['wallet_email'] = $loginUsername;
   echo  $_SESSION['wallet_email']

?>
```

Now I have noticed that once a new session id is generated, I lose the path specified in "session_save_path('sessions/')". This means I am unable to create new sessions.

I actually get the following error.

```
Warning: Unknown: open(sessions//sess_7af5c5f2f2bd83afff0203cc45190260, O_RDWR) failed:    No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (sessions/) in Unknown on line 0
```

Please I need urgent help with this.

Comment: double check permissions on the directory to make sure php has write. Also you probably want to specify a full absolute path such as `/some/dir/sessions` or else you might run into problems with trying to access php scripts under sub-directories where the script might try to look for a `session/` under the sub-directory that the script is being loaded.

Comment: Hello Jonathan, thanks for the comment. I will give you solution a try.  However I also just noticed that when I try to create a session variable from an include file, the session is not created. for example... if I have the following command in a file called "test.php",

    $_SESSION['test'] = 'ok'

then i do this in another file 

require_once ('test.php');

if i run the second file, the session variable is not created. Any help with this?

Comment: try setting the session path to an absolute path. included files are probably looking under a sub-folder for the session path. for example, document root is `/var/www/`, session path is `session/`. for a file under `/var/www/`, it will look in `/var/www/session/` for the session path. if a file under `/var/www/test/` is loaded, it will look in `/var/www/test/session/` for the session path. You want to make sure the session path is the same no matter where the script is loaded and the only way to do that is by using a full absolute path like `/var/www/session/`.

Comment: As Jonathan says, use an absolute path. The error ("no such directory") is pretty clear

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, use an absolute path for the parameter to `session_save_path( )`.  Here's why.

`session_save_path( )` and `session_regenerate_id( )` do not play nicely together when you use a relative path as a parameter to the former.  On my setup (Windows 7, Apache 2.2.25, php 5.3.27), I have the following index.php in c:\www\test:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set( 'America/New_York' );
ini_set( 'session.save_path', './sessions' );
//ini_set( 'session.save_path', 'c:/www/test/sessions' );

session_start( );
if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'count' ] )) {
    $_SESSION[ 'count' ] = 0;
}
$s1 = session_id( );
$b1 = $_SESSION[ 'count' ]++;
//session_regenerate_id( true );
$s2 = session_id( );
$b2 = $_SESSION[ 'count' ]++;
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <p><?php echo "$s1: $b1"; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo "$s2: $b2"; ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works just as you would think.  When I browse to the script:

- the same session ID is printed twice;
- an integer follows each session ID;
- the second integer is 1 greater than the first integer;
- refreshing the page causes the integers to grow by one with each successive refresh;
- the session file is found in directory c:\www\test\sessions (this directory MUST be created beforehand - PHP does not create it for you!);
- and that session file is updated with each successive refresh.

When I uncomment the session_regenerate_id( ) command and browse to my script:

- I get two *different* session IDs;
- upon refresh, the 1st session ID is the same as the previous page's second session ID;
- the integers are *always* 0 and 1 respectively;
- there is no session file in c:\www\test\sessions.  (If I pass 'false' to regen( ), then a series of empty session files will accumulate.)

When I instead use the second ini_set command (with the full path), it works fine.

The problem seems to be that the regen function confuses PHP: after the regen, PHP writes the session files to c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\sessions - or, it tries to, but fails if that directory has not already been created.  Once I created the second sessions directory, I saw sessions files show up there.  But PHP isn't looking there when I call session_start( ), so all the accumulated session knowledge is lost between script invocations.

I only figured this out because I was NOT getting 'directory does not exist' error messages in my 'php_errors.log' - at least, not where I was expecting.  I spotted another file by that name in the Apache2.2 directory.  In php.ini, I had specified a simple filename for my error_log directive, without the directory path.  Any error messages generated before the regen command went to c:\www\test\php_errors.log, but after the regen then went to the file in the Apache directory.  So the confusion regen causes appears to extend beyond the session functionality.